# How to import contacts into thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email

How to import contacts from a vCard file (`*vcf`) into Thunderbird mail client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on *Tools* in the top bar and then open the *Import* menu

[image: step1-screenshoot]

2. As *type of material* choice *"Address Book"* and click <kbd>Next</kbd>

   [image: step2-screenshoot]
3. As *type of file* choice *"vCard file (*.vcf)"* and click <kbd>Next</kbd>

   [image: step3-screenshoot]
4. Now search your file with the new window and open it.

If everything finished correctly, you will get a success message like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vkeQ.png) and when you open the address book you will see your imported contacts there.